# request.setAttribute("ob",ob) Expression language not working to display my ob

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jee

i used test Var and forward it to my Jsp page but when i use expression language to display it not working . My bean is well coded.everything was working .

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        FiliereDao filiereDb=new FiliereDao();
        String test="123";         // used to test
        request.setAttribute("listeFiliere",filiereDb.getFiliere());
        request.setAttribute("test",test);           


        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/admin.jsp").forward(request, response); 
    }
```

My jsp part not working : i can see 'hey z' displayed but my var test contained 123 i can't see it .

```
<c:forEach var="liste" items="${listeFiliere}">
            <li><c:out value="${ liste.idFiliere }" /> <c:out value="${ liste.nomFiliere }" /></li>
        </c:forEach>
 </ul>
<c:out value="${test}"/>      //expression language not working 
<c:out value="hey z"/>       // working
```

My web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>pfeKepler</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   .
   .
   .
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/taglibs.jsp</include-prelude>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

My jsp config :

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

i used test var but not displayed either .

### UPDATE

i tested my expression language in Eclipse 2019-09 with the same config Tomcat v7.0 jstl1.2 and it was working Fine . For now i'm usig Eclipse Kepler and i can't switch to the other . thanks in advance

### UPDATE2.0

problem resolved i was forwading my obj in the wrong Servlet thats why i can't get them in my jsp Dummy mistake .

Answer (score 0):

You can change from

```
<c:out value="${test}"/>
```

to

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.test}"/>
```